# Получить данные о языке страницы Polylang

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, polylang

Как можно получить локальный код страницы в плагине Polylang

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="сюда" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция для получения текущего языка: `pll_current_language`

```
pll_current_language($value);
```

где $value 'name', 'locale' или 'slug'.

Подробнее в документации: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/